# nginx load balancer w/ https and lets encrypt cert renewal

Tags: nginx, ssl, load-balancing, lets-encrypt

I have a small Linux VPS instance set up with nginx to proxy requests as a load balancer to multiple application servers.

All traffic is coming into https://app.example.com proxied to those upstream servers. Example nginx configuration for the load balancer:

```
upstream app_servers {
    server app-1.example.com;
    server app-2.example.com;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    include snippets/ssl-app.example.com.conf;
    include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

    server_name app.example.com;

    root /var/www/html;

    location / {
            # Set proxy headers
            proxy_set_header        Host $host;
            proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For 
            $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

            proxy_pass http://app_servers;
    }

    location ~ /.well-known {
            allow all;
    }

}
```

I set up letsencrypt and got certificate for app.example.com before setting up proxy and now I'm having trouble figure out how to configure nginx to proxy everything to the upstream app_servers except for anything to /.well-known so certbot can locally renew the SSL certificates on the server running this nginx load balancer. Any suggestions on how to route app.example.com/.well-known/ to a local path that letsencrypt certbot can use and hit successfully during renewal?

---

Update ensuring .well-known existed at /var/www/html (Debian) and setting root in conf allowed the certbot to renew properly. nginx conf snippet updated to reflect that.

Comment: The obvious thing to do is to set a `root`.

Comment: Can you clarify please? When I had a root set it was unaffected since all traffic is being proxied at /. Seems like there might be a way to exclude traffic to a root path outside of that but unsure of how

Comment: That's what the `location` is for.

Comment: nvm you were right setting root to proper path fixed it, I was confused about ramifications of setting root affecting proxy_pass. thx

Comment: Can you please answer your own question, show the working configuration you used so others trying to do this have a good reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting root to the default nginx webroot on Debian `/var/www/html` where certbot was originally configured to be pointed at for the .well-known folder resolved the issue.

```
upstream app_servers {
  server app-1.example.com;
  server app-2.example.com;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  listen 443 ssl;
  include snippets/ssl-app.example.com.conf;
  include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

  server_name app.example.com;

  root /var/www/html;

  location / {
    # Set proxy headers
    proxy_set_header        Host $host;
    proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For 
    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

    proxy_pass http://app_servers;
  }

  location ~ /.well-known {
    allow all;
  }
}
```